# can I use my mpd218 midi drum machine to run build tasks in VSCode?

Tags: visual-studio-code, midi

I have an Akai mpd218 drum machine, it's an midi controller. Is there a way to use this to run my build tasks in VSCode.

So I would tap a specific drum pad to run a build task

I tried VSLilypond but that's not really designed for this. Is it possible to configure the device as a numberpad and THEN have VSCode use it like a number pad?

For Mac

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got this working with [MIDIShortcuts](https://hautetechnique.com/midi/midishortcut/) 19.99 Euros after the free trial

I setup a keyboard shortcut on VSCode, then I setup the same keyboard shortcut in midishortcuts assigned to a specific drumpad.

Now I can tap my drumpad to run a build task in vscode. Ideally VSCode would just recognize my midi device and allow my to add the workspace commands... but this will work.

Those looking for more info on midi to qwerty keyboard, this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5928061/using-a-piano-keyboard-as-a-computer-keyboard) is full of info